# Create different theme for different instances of android studio

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0

I will give my use case first. I have two similar android studio projects which needs to be opened always. Now what happens is, I often make changes in wrong project because there is no easy way to identify which project I'm on by simply looking at UI (other than looking at the project name on top- which will go away on full screen). So it would be great if I could use dracula theme on one project and default theme on other. Is there any way to achieve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to change the background color of project pane and recent files window.

Goto Preference -> Appearance & Behavior -> File Colors -> {Add project files and set color}

[image]

Got the solution from [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206184059-Colour-Theme-per-project-)

Answer (score 1):

There is the ability to "to define any image as a background".

> *Set a background image for the current project only, or for any project you open or create anew.*

#### To set a background image

#### 1. Either press:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> twice (Searching Everywhere), or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Navigating to Action)

and start typing `set back`

#### 2. In the dialog box that opens,

Specify:

- the image you want to use as the background,
- its opacity,
- filling and placement options.

Choose to show background in:

- the editor and tool windows, or
- in the IntelliJ IDEA frame.

Selecting checkbox **`This project only`**:

- Show background in the current project and ignore this background in the other projects.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/setting-background-image.html